# Python class keeps giving me the same value

Tags: python, class

Hi im new to Python and im trying to figure out python classes.
I have made the following script, and I don't understand when I make the object vejr, outside the while loop, it keeps printing the same value over and over again.
If i make the object inside the while loop it works and print the temperature as it changes.
Inside the loop I make a new vejr object every time the loop runs, I thought it would be enough just make the vejr object once?? or is there a better way to write code like this?

```
import requests

import json

from datetime import datetime

import time


class Owm_data():

    def __init__(self, api_key="api_key", lat="51.507351", lon="-0.127758" ):
        
        self.api_key = api_key 
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon  
        self.url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=%s&lon=%s&appid=%s&units=metric" % (lat, lon, api_key)
        self.response = requests.get(self.url)
        self.data = json.loads(self.response.text)
          

    def get_temperature(self):
        return self.data["current"]["temp"]

    def get_pressure(self):
        return self.data["current"]["pressure"]



vejr = Owm_data()

while True:

    print(vejr.get_temperature())

    time.sleep(30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend distinguishing between temperature as an attribute versus a method. For instance:

```
class Owm_data():

    def __init__(self, api_key="api_key", lat="51.507351", lon="-0.127758" ):
        
        self.api_key = api_key 
        self.lat = lat
        self.lon = lon  
        self.temperature = self.get_temperature()

    def get_temperature(self):
        self.url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=%s&lon=%s&appid=%s&units=metric" % (lat, lon, api_key)
        self.response = requests.get(self.url)
        self.data = json.loads(self.response.text)
        self.temperature = self.data["current"]["temp"]
        return self.temperature
```

This way, if you want to access the cached value of the temperature, you can do `print(vejr.temperature)`. If you want to update the value of the temperature, you can do `print(vejr.get_temperature())`.  Although you might want to use a name that makes it clear that the temperature is being updated, such as `update_temperature()`.

Answer (score 1):

You pull the data when you *initialize* the class, and you only do that *outside* the loop. So your `vejr.get_temperature()` call is just reproducing the same cached information you saw at construction. If you want to recheck the data each loop, change from:

```
vejr = Owm_data()

while True:
    print(vejr.get_temperature())
    time.sleep(30)
```

to:

```
while True:
    vejr = Owm_data()
    print(vejr.get_temperature())
    time.sleep(30)
```

so the class is reconstructed on each loop and repulls the data.

Other solutions might include pulling the data each call to `get_temperature` and friends, rather than doing it in the initializer, but leaving the design as is is more useful when you *want* cached data so you can see both temperature and pressure from a single moment of time with one call.

Comment: Not worth its own answer, but If it were me I'd include an `_update(self)` method encapsulating the API request that could be called to update the data to give the option of using cached or new numbers

Comment: Hi, is it possible you can show an example, im trying to learn classes and how to use them the best possible way, thnx

Comment: @G.Anderson: Sure, that's an option. If the class is literally nothing but a pull-and-cache mechanism though, there's not much benefit to doing that versus just constructing a new instance when you need a new cache; the functional approach of "a given instance never changes" is nice in many contexts.